# Question on whether certain vectors span a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\{(x,y,z)|x≥0\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$. I want to find a basis for V, and I'm not sure whether $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)$ would qualify as a basis.

From the definition of a basis, the vectors must span V, which in this case they do as they span $\mathbb{R^3}$ and satisfy the condition $x≥0$. Also from the definition, the vectors must be linearly independent, which they clearly are in this case.

Is there something wrong with my reasoning? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $V$ is not a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Your set $V$ isn't even a vector space. For example, 
$$
c\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
is not in $V$ for negative values of $c$. It doesn't make sense to look for a basis (using the usual definition of "basis") for sets that aren't vector spaces.